# Bluetooth speaker sound distorted

Tags: sound, 18.04, bluetooth, pulseaudio

The sound from a bt speaker (JBL Flip 3) is distorted: sometimes ok for a few seconds but mainly it's crackling and interrupted intermittently.
Also the connection process is sometimes tricky... I have to connect/disconnect several times.

The same speaker is working fine on another Ubuntu 16.04 laptop.

What I tried so far:

- It's not an hardware or intenference issue: it's ok if I boot with Windows
- Within Ubuntu, another bt headset works fine
- The good old trick of switching profile (A2DP/HFP) and then disconnect/reconnect doesn't solve
- I've reinstalled `pulseaudio` and `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` with no luck

Furthermore, my `dmesg` is full of:

```
Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
```

Apparently others are experiencing the same issues: [Ubuntu 18.04 and bluetooth speaker JBL Charge 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029233/ubuntu-18-04-and-bluetooth-speaker-jbl-charge-3/1036127)

**UPDATE:**

- I've tried another JBL speaker (charge 3): same problem
- I've updated bluez to v5.50, no luck

Comment: Same here. Any known solutions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok, I finally got through this. :)

Simply: the sound is distorted only while the **Bluetooth settings** window is open and scanning for devices. Closing the windows clears the sound.

Comment: Oh, yeah.. for me and 18.10 and some Jabra headphone, it was also that the bluetooth settings window was open! Thanks

Comment: for me it was here a problem for weeks and searching for a solution some how it is over... maybe the speaker got scared ..... so i did not do any thing...

Comment: I'd been looking for an answer to this problem for _years_; I just closed the bluetooth settings window (often open when I'm connecting a speaker..) and the crackling went away **instantly**  Thanks!

Comment: awesome observation! mine JBL speakers too! Thanks!

Comment: Wow! I had the same problem with two different bluetooth speakers. Closing the settings window instantly fixed the problem!! (and both are not JBL)

Comment: Whoho! I got my ny Bose bluetooth headphones to stop making distorted sounds... just by closing the settings dialog. And the settings dialog was not even on the bluetooth settings. (This just feels sooooo... weird.)

Comment: I had this both on a JBL speaker and on my Shure Aonic 50 headphones! A very amateurish bug from the Ubuntu team that continues to this day.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

1. Update your `bluez` version:

   - Open the terminal and check the current bluez version in your system with the following command: `dpkg --status bluez | grep '^Version:'` (in my case I received version: 5.48-0ubuntu3.1)
   - Add the following repository to get the last version of bluez (5.50 as of November 2018):

     `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bluetooth/bluez
     sudo apt-get update`
   - After running the command you should be able to update to bluez 5.50 via:

     `sudo apt upgrade`
2. Disable bluetooth
3. Install `blueman` from Ubuntu Software Center
4. Open `blueman`, search for devices, find and mark as trusted
5. ..and voila - the sound from bluetooth speaker is clear and without distortions

Bluez install credit: https://medium.com/@overcode/fixing-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-pop-os-18-04-d4b8dbf7ddd6

Comment: Full of hope I went thru until #5, I was almost saying "voila - the sound from bluetooth speaker is clear and without distortions" but.... no luck, same as before even with bluez v5.50.
Thank you for your try

Comment: I also updated my BIOS to the latest version, maybe that also played a role

Comment: Check my answer. You also got the point installing blueman (unfortunately my "setting" window was still open in the background). Anyway  blueman is not the solution and it's not a problem of the default bluetooth manager: also blueman produce the same distortion while "searching", the difference is that blueman seraches only when you tell him to do so, while the default bluetooth manager is constantly searching.

Comment: This solved my problem, Thanks

Comment: worked for my dell 7559

Comment: Worked out great, thanks. However the sound is too low, trying to figure this out now.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the things written above. It didnt worked out quite well. Then I simply restarted BT.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart
```

Thats it!